# Defining Winkel Tripel in proj 4.8.0?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I have QGIS with proj 4.8.0 installed. I'd like to add Winkel Tripel projection which seems to be defined as

```
+proj=wintri
```

But that definition string does not work. Is this a bug in my proj version, or what's the correct definition string?

Comment: Works for me: echo "34 -34" | proj "+proj=wintri"

Comment: Yes, that echos something. But if I define a custom CRS with this string, nothing gets reprojected in QGIS. Guess I'd need some more parameters?

Comment: No, the fact that it's re-projecting on the command-line seems to indicate it works. Is it possible that QGIS has a proj library bundled different from the one you think you have? Or that QGIS actually checks the projection strings itself before passing them on to proj? (And hasn't heard of Winkel yet?)

Comment: @Paul Ramsey: It seems that even though the Winkel Tripel projection is defined in the `proj` library and can be called from the command line, it can't be used as a custom CRS in QGIS because there's no inverse transformation in the `proj` library (see http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2012-May/006302.html). And it seems that the inverse transformation isn't trivial (and will always be an approximation...).

Comment: I think you should write that into an answer, as it is... the answer. The command-line tools also refuse to do an inverse projection.

Comment: I'm guessing one can add the inverse to Proj4 or maybe even as a QGIS plugin (see https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/blob/master/src/winkel3.js#L12 for a Javascript implementation of the inverse)? Trying to learn more about both these options.

Comment: As the collegues mentiond above, if you have also with proj +proj=aitoff have the same problems, it is a matter of missing inverse projection see: (+proj=aitoff; Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009
<invproj>: inverse projection not available) and ( invproj +proj=wintri; Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009
<invproj>: inverse projection not available ). Strange but good to know

Comment: I added an enhancement request on the PROJ issue tracker: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ticket/234

Comment: ... which got rejected because there is no easy mathematical solution for the inverse projection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Summing up the discussion above:*

While Winkel Tripel projection is defined in the proj library and can be called from the command line, it can't be used as a custom CRS in QGIS [because there's **no inverse transformation**](http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2012-May/006302.html) in the proj library.

[The enhancement request to add this functionality has been closed](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ticket/234) since it seems that the inverse transformation isn't trivial.

Comment: Could this be different now? I am, with `pyproj==1.9.5.1` installed, able to do: `pp = Proj(proj='wintri', lon_0=47.); pp(*pp(0,0), inverse=True)` which returns `(0,0)` (to machine precision), i.e., I'm able to reverse the forward transform with the `inverse=True` keyword. Since this pyproj seems to have the inverse, could QGIS support this now?